# Trouble with Calc 1 Cylindrical Shells Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Apologies if this question appears elementary to some of you but I need help understanding where I went wrong.

So the problem I am having trouble with is this: The area bounded by the curve y = $x^2$ and the line y = 4 generates a solid of revolution when rotated about the y-axis. Find the volume.

So I figured to myself, since my functions are solved for y (in terms of x), this is a cylindrical shells problem.

To find my bounds and to determine which function is on top and which function is on the bottom, I set $x^2$ =  4 and found that x = -2 and x = 2. So my bounds of integration are x = -2 and x = 2. On that interval, $x^2$ is the bottom function while y = 4 is the top function.

Since my functions are solved for y and we will rotate about the y-axis, this is a cylindrical shells problem. So I set it up the integral like so:

$\int_{-2}^2 2{\pi}x(4-x^2) \,dx$

And then I solved like so:

$\int_{-2}^2 2{\pi}x(4-x^2) \,dx$

= $2{\pi} \int_{-2}^2x(4-x^2) \,dx$

=$2{\pi} \int_{-2}^24x-x^3 \,dx$

When I evaluate the above line, I get:

$2 {\pi} [(2(2)^2 - \frac{(2)^4}4 +C) - (2(-2)^2 - \frac{(-2)^4}4 +C) )]$

= $2 {\pi} [(8-4 + C - (8 - 4 + C)]$
= 0

Obviously, that is incorrect.

However, I am not sure what I did wrong. Maybe I set up my integral wrong as when I take the above integral from 0 to 2, I get the right answer of ${8 \pi}$. That makes sense since we are rotating about the y-axis (x = 0), the lower bound should be 0 instead of -2. Any help would be appreciated and any additional resources this community may have for me to help me learn calculus better will also be helpful.

Thank you!

Also, I hope my formatting was not that bad. Sorry if it is.

Comment: Your region is revolving around the y axis. The revolving part is in first quadrant only.

Comment: Make a picture of what you did.  The area of the region to the right of the y axis sweeps out an area with "negative volume" and the area to the right of the y axis has the oposite positive volume.  If you change your bounds of integration to $\int_0^2 xf(x)\ dx$ you will get the right answer.

Comment: Having this integral, $ \  \int_{-2}^2 \ \ 4x-x^3 \ \ dx \ \ , $ is going to give you zero because you are integrating an odd-symmetry function over an interval symmetric about the $ \ y-$axis.  As remarked in the other comments, when you are working out a volume of a solid of revolution, you want to revolve a region that lies on only one side of the "rotation axis".